# How to search in DataGridView using WindowsForms with the data already loaded?

Tags: c#, datagridview, windows-forms-designer

I know you will be thinking that this question is already duplicated but Nope. I want to implement a search method to find data in my DataGridView using WindowsForms but most of the solutions I found over the internet they use code to search in the database. There is not point to search in the database when data is already loaded in the DataGridView.

I found this:
[How to search in Data gridview in C# Windows Form application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21829858/how-to-search-in-data-gridview-in-c-sharp-windows-form-application/21831418)

but code from link didn't work for me (No errors, just does nothing):

```
    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
        bs.DataSource = Listaventas.DataSource;
        bs.Filter = "Nombre" + " like '%" + textBox1.Text + "%'";
        Listaventas.DataSource = bs;

    }
```

I am using Entity Framework to load data in my DataGridView, but I want to make a search in the DataGridView with the data already loaded.

This is my code:

```
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);

        BindingSource source = new BindingSource();
        var ventas = _facturasRepository.GetListVentas();
        source.DataSource = ventas;
        Listaventas.DataSource = typeof(List<>); 
        Listaventas.DataSource = source;
        Listaventas.Columns.Add("Column", "Test");
        Listaventas.Columns["Column"].DefaultCellStyle.NullValue = "Add";
    }

    public IList<Factura> GetListVentas()
    {
       return _context.Facturas.OrderByDescending(a => a.FechaVenta).ToList();
    }
```

[image]

I am trying to make a search in the DataGridView with the data already loaded. I think the search should accept all columns text. Most internet solutions tries to make a search by making a database call, but I do not find any sense in my case because I have data already loaded in the component.

How do I code this?

Comment: You may want to “describe what” _”didn't work for me”_ ... are there errors? No results returned from the filter?

Comment: No errors, just does nothing. I think the provided code in the link is trying to make a search in the database, but I do not want to make any search in database.

Comment: I could be mistaken however, I believe the `List<T>` you are using needs to implement the `IBindingListView` interface to filter. You can do this using a `DataTable` or in your case, I would think that filtering the `List<T>` would be easiest using LINQ. There are plenty of examples of how to filter a `List<T>` using LINQ.

Comment: Example… `var filter = ventas.Where(x => x.Nombre.Contains(textBox1.Text));` … `Listaventas.DataSource = filter.ToList();`

Comment: Worked... but this is still performing a database search.

Comment: Why do you say that? It is filtering the `List<T>` `ventas`. The only call (I am guessing) to the DB is from the line of code… `var ventas = _facturasRepository.GetListVentas();` Am I missing something?

Comment: You are a true HERO! Sorry, I got you. I was very tired finding solutions and you solved this. Thanks.

Comment: I thought this was going to be complex but you made this easy.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223311/discussion-between-ares-and-johng).